# How can I get type of external login provider from authenticated user in ASP.MVC 4?

Tags: model-view-controller, oauth, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ASP.MVC 4 with an account controller that uses forms authentication. I added Facebook and Twitter as an external login providers using OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient etc. Now I want to get User login type (Facebook, Twitter, login/password etc) in the controller and in the view. How can I get this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I fount answer by myself in the AccountController, action RemoveExternalLogins :

```
ICollection<OAuthAccount> accounts = OAuthWebSecurity.GetAccountsFromUserName(User.Identity.Name);
```

and account contain provider field - account.Provider. For Facebook it will be "Facebook".